# How to output the content of a Scenegraph in JavaFX 2 to an Image

Tags: java, javafx-2

How to output the content of a `Scene` graph in JavaFX 2 to an `Image`. Actually, I am working on an app, which basically designs cards. So, the user just clicks to the various options to customize the scene. Finally I would like to export the scene content to an Image file. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In FX 2.2 new snapshot feature appeared for that matter. You can just say

```
WritableImage snapshot = scene.snapshot(null);
```

---

With older FX you can use AWT Robot. This is not very good approach as it requires whole AWT stack to start.

```
            // getting screen coordinates of a node (or whole scene)
            Bounds b = node.getBoundsInParent(); 
            int x = (int)Math.round(primaryStage.getX() + scene.getX() + b.getMinX());
            int y = (int)Math.round(primaryStage.getY() + scene.getY() + b.getMinY());
            int w = (int)Math.round(b.getWidth());
            int h = (int)Math.round(b.getHeight());
            // using ATW robot to get image
            java.awt.Robot robot = new java.awt.Robot();
            java.awt.image.BufferedImage bi = robot.createScreenCapture(new java.awt.Rectangle(x, y, w, h));
            // convert BufferedImage to javafx.scene.image.Image
            java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // or you can write directly to file instead
            ImageIO.write(bi, "png", stream);
            Image image = new Image(new java.io.ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray()), w, h, true, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

JavaFX 2.2 (jdk7u6) added a Node [snapshot to image](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.util.Callback,%20javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) feature which would be the preferred way of accomplishing this task.

---

Prior to 2.2, JavaFX currently does not have a public function to convert a Node or Scene to an Image.  There is an open feature request for this http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-13751 (anybody can sign up to view the current feature request status).

As a workaround in the meantime, you could use Swing/AWT functions to convert the JavaFX scene to an image and write the resultant image to a file:

```
BufferedImage img = new Robot().createScreenCapture(
  new java.awt.Rectangle(
    (int)sceneRect.getX(),       (int)sceneRect.getY(),
    (int)sceneRect.getWidth()-1, (int)sceneRect.getHeight()-1));
File file = File.createTempFile("card", ".jpg");
ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", file);
```

The above code is paraphrased from: [JavaFXDev: Screen capture tool](http://www.aljoscha-rittner.de/blog/archive/2011/03/09/javafxdev-screen-capture-tool-with-200-lines-and-500ms-startup-time/).

The sceneRect can be determined by:

```
Stage stage = (Stage) scene.getWindow();
stage.toFront();
Rectangle sceneRect = new Rectangle(
  stage.getX() + scene.getX(), stage.getY() + scene.getY(), 
  scene.getWidth(), scene.getHeight());
```

If you follow the above idiom, be careful of threading - such that code accessing the live JavaFX scene only runs on the JavaFX Application Thread and the AWT code only runs on the AWT thread.

Comment: Looks like Sergey already posted a solution while I was writing my answer - seems like the two solutions are pretty similar ;-)  I'll leave my duplicate answer as it contains a couple of useful links.