# How to convert node to image in javafx 2.1?

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I am using Java FX and I would like to convert a node to an image. I found this resource, but it does not solve my problem as I want to convert a node to an image, not a whole scene.

[How to output the content of a Scene graph in JavaFx 2.0 to an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9215360/how-to-output-the-content-of-a-scene-graph-in-javafx-2-0-to-an-image)

Comment: I don't know much about this and don't have the time to test, but couldn't you just create a new scene and add the node you want to convert to an image to it as the sole child and then use the method explained in the link? I'm guessing you never have to show the second scene you create.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is solution of my problem. This solution is help of Sergey and jewelsea. This solution is in javafx 2.2. Thanks Sergey and jewelsea.

```
public class TrySnapshot extends Application {

javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils fXUtils;
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(550, 400, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
File file = new File("C:/Users/PC1/Desktop/Sample Images/test.jpg");
VBox vbox = null;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    vbox = new VBox();
    Button btn = new Button();
    Image i = new Image("file:C:\\Koala.jpg");
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    imageView.setImage(i);
    vbox.getChildren().add(imageView);
    vbox.setSpacing(10);
    btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        // here we make image from vbox and add it to scene, can be repeated :)
       WritableImage snapshot = vbox.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
           vbox.getChildren().add(new ImageView(snapshot));
            saveImage(snapshot);
            System.out.println(vbox.getChildren().size());
        }
    });


    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(btn), 500, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void saveImage(WritableImage snapshot) {
    BufferedImage image;
    image = javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, bufferedImage);
    try {
        Graphics2D gd = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();
        gd.translate(vbox.getWidth(), vbox.getHeight());
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TrySnapshot.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    };
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use new FX 2.2 snapshot feature:

```
public class TrySnapshot extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final VBox vbox = new VBox(2);
        final Button btn = new Button();
        vbox.getChildren().add(btn);
        btn.setText("Say 'Hello World'");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                // here we make image from vbox and add it to scene, can be repeated :)
                WritableImage snapshot = vbox.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);

                vbox.getChildren().add(new ImageView(snapshot));
                System.out.println(vbox.getChildren().size());
            }
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(vbox), 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
```

---

If you must use older FX for some reason just change scene coordinates to your node coordinates using  `Node#getBoundsInParent` calls in the code sample you linked.

Comment: Thanks Sergey. But snaphot() method is not solution of my problem. I want bufferedimage some thing.

Comment: You can get an awt buffeted image using Sergey's solution and [SwingFXUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html#fromFXImage(javafx.scene.image.Image,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImage))

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where i wanted to convert a node, given from a mousevent, to an image.

This one works for me perfectly:

```
Image image = ((ImageView) node).getImage();
```