# JavaFX: get BufferedImage from path

Tags: java, javafx-2

Coming from AWT/Swing, I've started experimenting a bit with JavaFX the last few days. I realized that what I used to do in thousands lines of codes can now be done in a few hundred.

One problem I came across is, however, the following: I'm trying to develop a small painting app where the user can choose brush size and color for its strokes. For all the strokes the user makes, I use the JavaFX class `Path` and add these paths to a `Group` (which is added to a `Pane`) where they are - automagically - painted. Now I want to store the resulting image as a jpg and try to raster all the paths in a BufferedImage. However, I found no functions in the API that help me do that.

I tried to use `Canvas` and its `GraphicsContext`, but that did not help. How could I raster all the JavaFX `Path`s from a list on an image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Take a [snapshot](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#snapshot%28javafx.scene.SnapshotParameters,%20javafx.scene.image.WritableImage%29) of your Group to get a JavaFX Image.
2. Use [SwingFXUtils](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingFXUtils.html) to convert your JavaFX image snapshot to a buffered image.
3. Use [ImageIO](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) to convert your buffered image to a jpeg, png, etc

Comment: @tarrsalah suggests to check out [this question for a running example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330720/how-to-convert-node-to-image-in-javafx-2-1) =)