# Rectangle indicate to a specific media player javafx

Tags: javafx, screenshot

in this JavaFX project

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private MediaView media_view;

    private Media me;
    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
        String s="/home/mustafa987/Videos/sampels/video10.mp4";
        me=new Media(new File(s).toURI().toString());
        mp=new MediaPlayer(me);
        media_view.setMediaPlayer(mp);
        mp.play();
        mp.setRate(1);

        Robot robot=new Robot();

        Rectangle rectangle=new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        //in the line above the Rectangle indicate to the desktop screen so the robot can capture the screenshot  

        BufferedImage buffer=robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
        //take screenshot
        Image image=SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(buffer, null);
    }
}
```

How can I make the Rectangle indicates to the program MediaView instead of the desktop screen (or) if there a way to make the robot directly indicates to the program MediaView
and thanks

Comment: I do not know if you absolutely have to use a `robot`, but it seems weird to use Swing/awt component to have an image of a JavaFx component while JavaFX node has a native one with `Node.snapshot(...)`. Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330720/how-to-convert-node-to-image-in-javafx-2-1) can help.

Comment: @pagbo thanks for your hint very much, and also if you know a way to make my record my MediaView instead of robot so, please tell me about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not really know your needs, but it does not make really sense to make an image in the initialize method to me.

One quick solution could be the following one :

```
public class FXMLDocumentController extends BorderPane {

   @FXML
   private MediaView mediaView;

   @FXML
   private VBox container;

   private Media me;

   private MediaPlayer mp;

   /**
    * Constructor.
    */
   public FXMLDocumentController() {
      FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Media.fxml"));
      loader.setRoot(this);
      loader.setController(this);

      try {
         loader.load();
      } catch(IOException e) {
         System.out.println("An error occurs while trying to load the media component." + e);
      }
   }

   @FXML
   private void initialize() {
      // String s = "/home/mustafa987/Videos/sampels/video10.mp4";
      // me = new Media(new File(s).toURI().toString());
      // mp = new MediaPlayer(me);
      // mediaView.setMediaPlayer(mp);
      // mp.play();
      // mp.setRate(1);
   }

   @FXML
   private void handleSnap() throws IOException {
      System.out.println("User asks snap.");
      WritableImage img = container.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
      BufferedImage bufImg = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(img, null);
      ImageIO.write(bufImg, "png", new File("./save/snap.png"));
   }
}
```

It takes a snapshot of the `VBox` containing the `MediaView` cause I have no media to display, but it should also work with `MediaView` as this component inherits from `Node`.

As you did not provide it, this is the FXML file I used :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.MediaView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" type="BorderPane">
    <top>
        <GridPane >
            <children>
                <Label GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="0" text="Snap frame" />
                <HBox GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1"  alignment="CENTER">
                    <children>
                        <Button text="Take snap.." onAction="#handleSnap" />
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
            <columnConstraints>
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="90.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints percentWidth="10.0" />
            </columnConstraints>
        </GridPane>
    </top>

    <center>
        <VBox fx:id="container" style="-fx-background-color:rgb(200,200,200); -fx-border-color:DARKBLUE">
            <children>
                <Label text="Media Player"/>
                <MediaView fx:id="mediaView"/>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>
    <bottom>
        <Label text="Not in the snap scope (NITSS)"/>
    </bottom>
    <left>
        <Label text="NITSS"/>
    </left>
    <right>
        <Label text="NITSS"/>
    </right>
</fx:root>
```

Comment: I'm just asking why when I looking on the web for great examples like yours I never find one! , genius solution instead of robot thanks you very much !!!!

Comment: I think I don't know the proper keyword to locking for maybe :(

Comment: You're welcome. Actually I think you are too focused on your problem. You should get an overview of your purpose. I have not invented the solution I give you, It was based on the link I provided you as comment of your question. 
But do not worried,it comes with time and experience :).