# How to draw underlined text in a JavaFX Canvas

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I'm trying to draw underlined text in a JavaFX 8 canvas. I need to draw directly to the canvas instead of using a Text node since I will then export the canvas to image and use it elsewhere.

I haven't found a way to configure the `GraphicsContext` to make it draw underlined text.

So far I've discovered:

- The `Font` Constructor takes a font family, a font weight (bold, regular, etc) and a font posture (whether it is italic or not) but there is no sign of a *underlined* property.
- To format text as underlined in a `Text` element you set the `setUnderline` property but the `Text` element is a `Node` and I'm trying to draw directly into the Canvas not placing a `Node` on top of it.

Is there a way to draw underlined text directly on a GraphicsContext? If not, Is there a workaround that would let me export it to an image?

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but why do you need to draw on the canvas in order to export an image? You can convert any `Node` (including layout panes and all their children) to an image natively... Just use the [snapshot feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12330720/how-to-convert-node-to-image-in-javafx-2-1) in JavaFX 2.2+

Comment: Also consider `strokeLine()` in a `GraphicsContext` or an  `AttributedString` in a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: @Zephyr I'm working on a illustrator-type tool where I need to manipulate shapes and draw ribbons and resizing handles around them in response to user actions. I figured out that using the canvas and an animation loop whas the proper way forward.